# Deny access to servlets placed inside WEB-INF

Tags: jakarta-ee, servlets

I'm trying to block access to servlets whose .class files are inside WEB-INF/classes. I'm using annotation for mapping servlets. Actually I can't directly access jsp files there are into WEB-INF, but I still can access all the servlets by digiting in the url bar. I don't want this because if accessed like that they popup lots of errors (they won't if accessed properly and not by url). Also I couldn't find anything on the Internet to fix this, expect the url blocking method using the path in the web.xml.

P.s. Sorry for my bad english.

**EDIT**:

I'm not using web.xml for mapping, but the annotation @WebServlet. For example, I have a servlet with this annotation `@WebServlet("/searchServlet")`. If I type in the url "localhost/searchServlet", it is called instead of displaying the error "resource not found" like with jsp into WEB-INF. Could it be a problem of deployment? All I'm doing is defining the Java Build Path for my src java classes into WEB-INF/classes (so it's actually the output of the compiled source): maybe this is different from deploying?

I want them being accessed only through gets/posts/redirects/forwards...

Comment: So you wanna block the Servlets' URL? How about just taking out the mapping from the web.xml? Are you using them for something else?

Comment: @Fabio Rende  URLs cannot see anything under WEB-INF. If you are getting error, please paste it.

Comment: You want to block for example all http://localhost:8080/context/WEB-INF/classes/... ?

Comment: What is the point of having a servlet that's not going to be accessed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Filter](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html) to intercept all (or subset of) requests in your web application and, for example perform redirect to some predefined error page in filter.

You will need to add filter mapping in your web.xml (you also can annotate filter with relevant Servlet 3.0 annotations) and you won't have to touch your servlets mapped with annotations.

**UPDATE:** You can look [here](https://blogs.oracle.com/swchan/entry/servlet_3_0_annotations) on how to define filter with annotations. You can do something like this in `doFilter`:

```
HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;
httpResponse.sendRedirect("/index.jsp");
```

... if you do want to block current request.

Hope this will help.

Comment: I tried this, it blocks all the requests. I want to access to servlets through form submit for example. I just don't want to access by directly digiting into url.

Comment: @FabioRende not sure that I've understood you. Typical application have, say, url "/something". If user accesses this url entering it in browser's address bar - GET request will be performed and servlet will respond with form. Once user submits form POST will be served by servlet. What exact part of this workflow you want to block?

Comment: If you block all GET requests user will never be able to fetch form in the first place. Theoretically you can build your server the way that it will have only one "entry point url" that will be allowed to serve GET requests. And all other redirects\navigation will be done using POST requests, but you will definitely have to reimplement lots of your servlets\jsps, not to mention that this is misusing HTTP.